# Array items not displaying properly

Tags: java, arrays, adt

I'm trying to write a program to practice some basic ADT methods like insert, append etc but my array won't print out the write items. I already programmed it in c++ and i'm trying to redo it in java. Everything looks right but it only prints out 5 zeros(since the length of the array is 5). Here is the code and thanks for the help:

```java
public class newADTClass {
    int length;
    int size;
    int[] Array;

    public newADTClass(int[] Array, int size, int length) {
        Array = new int[10];
        this.Array = Array;
        this.length = length;
        this.size = size;
    }

    void display(newADTClass arr) {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Elements are \n");
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", arr.Array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        newADTClass arr2 = new newADTClass(arr1, 10, 5);
        arr2.display(arr2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program is hard to follow. It can be refactored significantly. But to stay on track, your problem with the code is here: 
`Array = new int [10]`. In this line, you replace the constructor Array parameter with a newly initialized array. I think if you remove this line, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new blank array in the constructor. If you remove `Array = new int [10];`, from the constructor then the code will work.

```java
public newADTClass(int[] Array, int size, int length) {
    this.Array = Array;
    this.length = length;
    this.size = size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign absulutely new created array object to this.Array instead of the Array parameter. By default int[] values are 0.